# Variable selection (automated)

Tags: feature-selection

I was wondering whether the following mechanical selection procedure will result in a possible bias. First let me introduce the first procedure, we start with a model and only look at the t-value and possibly correct them for it (heteroskedasticity / autocorrelation). We then only add variables into our final model that are significant. However I am well aware this gives us a bias with F-test, since even though some variables can be insignificant, they can be jointly significant.

However if we also take that into account, whether adding that variable gives us a "sensible" subset to do a F-test on and only add them if they give a significant result (indicating joinly significance), this would then actually be a pretty good automated method or does this give some bias? Will anything happen that we do **not** like to have?

Furthermore is a forward variable selection (starting with small set and increase it) better or backwards variable selection better?

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: The more comparisons, the more data driven. You might want to study Frank Harrell's famous book 'Regression Modelling Strategies' to get a feeling about this.

Comment: Using an automated selection procedure is like telling your boss to pay you less. :-).

Comment: The litany of issues with automated model selection are discussed at some length in numerous answers on the site; useful links and book suggestions can be found in many of them. The previous recommendation of Harrell's book would be one I'd add my voice to. I regularly ask prospective research students to make sure they at least read chapter 4.